# Eraser: "Warning: This computer has had System Restore or Volume Shadow Copies enabled.". Does my USB flash drive contain any copies of files stored?

Tags: windows-7, usb, security, eraser

I use  [Eraser](https://eraser.heidi.ie/) to try to safely erase any content present on my USB flash drive. After the erasure, I read in the log:

> Session: Monday, March 27, 2017 6:13:52 PM
>   Monday, March 27, 2017 6:13:52 PM   Warning This computer has had System Restore or Volume Shadow Copies enabled. This may allow copies of files stored on the disk to be recovered and pose a security concern.

Does it mean the USB flash drive still contains any  copies of files? or are these  copies of files stored in a different drive?

[image]

[image]

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate and Eraser 6.2.0.2979.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have enabled shadow volumes you are fine. This message is very common, because system restore is enabled by default and it MAY to store data elsewhere, however unless the USB was plugged in all the time, it is a low chance that the data would be elsewhere.

I see this warning all the time for USB and because I only plug the USB to copy files and remove it, the files never make it elsewhere...